# How will I use breeze with Entity Framework 6 with .net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, breeze, entity-framework-6

I installed my 4.0 MVC project, Entity Framework 6 using nuget(to enable ode first migrations). Then I tried installing breeze package Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6. But I'm having missing assembly reference errors for breeze.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only way I was able to get Breeze working on .NET 4.0 with Entity Framework 6 was to create my own EF6ContextProvider using the [Breeze source code from GitHub](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze) as a starting point.

I created a project `Breeze.WebApi.EF6` and added a class `EF6ContextProvider.cs` that was pretty much a direct copy of the `EFContextProvider.cs` in the official `Breeze.WebApi.EF` project.  The only real changes were to rename the namespace and the class, and adjust the `using` statements for EF6 (the code is too long to post).  This project has NuGet references to `Breeze.Server.WebApi.Core` and `EntityFramework` - the Breeze package pulls in a bunch of dependencies, and I had to add references to a couple of system assemblies to get it to compile.

Then, in my MVC/WebAPI project I just had NuGet references for `Breeze.Client` and `Breeze.Server.WebApi.Core` and a project reference to the `Breeze.WebApi.EF6` project.

Obviously this is a bit of a hack.  I have created a [UserVoice item for official support](http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5235784-support-entity-framework-6-with-webapi-1-net-4-).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6 is the only package from Breeze that you've installed. That's not enough. You need to install "Breeze Server - for Web API 2" (Breeze.Server.WebApi2).

You should have these lines in your packages.config:

```
<package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider" version="1.4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6" version="1.4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Breeze.Server.WebApi2" version="1.4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: I need this to be done in .Net 4.0. But Breeze.Server.WebApi2 requires 4.5