# 404 when access Breeze controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, breeze, asp.net-mvc-5, hottowel

I created an Asp.Net MVC 5 project and then used NuGet to add hottowl (which includes Breeze).
I have the following controller.

```
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<ApplicationDbContext> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<ApplicationDbContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Event> Events()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Events;
    }
}
```

And the following code exists in file BreezeWebApiConfig.cs. However, I always got the 404 error when try to access `http://localhost:49890/Breeze/Events`. Did I miss anything? Or is the following breeze routing not working?

```
using System.Web.Http;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(
    typeof(ST13a.App_Start.BreezeWebApiConfig), "RegisterBreezePreStart")]
namespace ST13a.App_Start {
  ///<summary>
  /// Inserts the Breeze Web API controller route at the front of all Web API routes
  ///</summary>
  ///<remarks>
  /// This class is discovered and run during startup; see
  /// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/10/11/light-up-your-nupacks-with-startup-code-and-webactivator.aspx
  ///</remarks>
  public static class BreezeWebApiConfig {

    public static void RegisterBreezePreStart() {
      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "BreezeApi",
          routeTemplate: "breeze/{controller}/{action}"
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a portion of your route -

```
http://localhost:49890/breeze/Breeze/Events
```

Should work

If you want to not be redundant you could either change your prefix ('breeze') or change the controller name ('Breeze')

Answer (score 0):

Are you using latest breeze?  See [How will I use breeze with Entity Framework 6 with .net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032288/how-will-i-use-breeze-with-entity-framework-6-with-net-4-0)  which said "You need to install "Breeze Server - for Web API 2" (Breeze.Server.WebApi2).". Try update your hottowel package and try.

As of 11/19/2013, out of the 4 hottowel packages, I only see this one use Breeze.Sever.WebApi2: HotTowel.Angular.Breeze .  Maybe the other packages need update to support WebApi2.